# Xsl foreach variable

Tags: xslt, foreach

I have an XML with this structure, and I am doing a foreach for all the item. But I want to make a markup with this structure.
The first div with the class "col-md-4", the next two divs with the class "col-md-6", and repeat that logic as in the example. I really do not know how to do it, because I can not use variables inside the foreach, well I do but not exist accumulative variable.
Someone can give me a hand?

```
<items>
 <item>A</item>
 <item>B</item>
 <item>C</item>
 <item>D</item>
 <item>E</item>
 <item>F</item>
 <item>G</item>
 <item>H</item>
 <item>I</item>
 <item>J</item>
</items>
```

Example:

```
  <div class="col-md-4">
    A
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    B
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    C
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    D
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    E
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    F
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    G
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use position of current element in foreach with some basic math:

```
<xsl:for-each select="item">
  <div>
    <xsl:attribute name="class">
      <xsl:choose>
        <!-- every third item starting from the first one is col-md-4, others - col-md-6 --> 
        <xsl:when test="(position() - 1) mod 3 = 0">col-md-4</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>col-md-6</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
</div>
```